# Run a Powershell script from Batch file with elevated privileges?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to run `example.ps1` from `code.bat`

I realize that the `start` command would run it but require that it be run as admin, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your batch file:

```
powershell -Command "&{ Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-File C:\folder\psfile.ps1' -Verb RunAs}"
```

...basically you're using Powershell to run Powershell. The second instance is elevated to Admin and is running your script with those permissions.

---

Full explanation:

`Start-Process` can be used to run a program, and also has the parameter `-Verb RunAs` which elevates the program to run as Admin.

We can't call `Start-Process` from a batch file as it's a PowerShell command.

But we can run `powershell` from a batch file, then using the `-command` parameter to run `Start-Process`.

We use `Start-Process` to run `powershell` (again) and run your script when it is elevated to Admin: `-ArgumentList '-File C:\folder\psfile.ps1' -Verb RunAs`

Comment: I've gotten this far.

Comment: powershell -noprofile -command "&{ Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -File %path%Resources\Found\WindowsSecurity.ps1' -Verb RunAs}"

Comment: Thanks for your help already!  Could you explain just slightly more? :D

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thank you for being so kind.