# Run Powershell script via batch file with elevated privileges

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting, system-administration

I need to run a Powershell script to create AD user via a batch file. The thing is I need to run this PS script with elevated privileges (domain admin account). I have tried to script a '.bat' file which encloses all this information but I have been unsuccessful so far. Here is the script :

```
echo off
cls
echo Sign in with your ADM ID
set /p username=

powershell -noprofile -command "&{ start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-
noprofile -file C:\Users\...\Desktop\Powershell_scripts\New-ADuser\New-
Aduser_test.ps1' -verb RunAs}"
```

I have tried with line /netonly /user:adm@domain but It won't work.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post more details.. does it error? Does it fail silently? How are you running it - ordinary desktop or scheduled task or other script environment?

Comment: If you are asking if you can run as administrator without provoking a UAC prompt, the answer is "no." If that's not your question, you need to clarify what you really want to do.

Comment: Why do you need a batch file?

Comment: @Charlypop, as you said in your last comment, there are many things involved. An excel form that calls a bat file that calls a powershell script. Saying it doesn't work is not the kind of information nedded to see where the error is. You should, at least, post the form's bat caller code, the bat file code, and the powershell script (or at least the relevant details). Also, you may post some other details ie, computer OS, is it running into a domain or not, is the powershell code running on local or remote computer, is user admin or not... Please clarify these points. There are some workarounds

Comment: Ok. The Excel form generates a CSV file which contains all the needed information to run the PS script which is a New-ADuser script. These form and script are to be run from domain. To be able to create a new AD user the script has to be executed with a domain admin account. The process is like : fill in the Excel form with all the user's details, add all these in the CSV sheet via a button, and then click on a final button which executes the PS script. BTW computer OS => Windows 7, 10 ; code running on local computer or shared drive ; admin users exclusively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally ended up with this :

```
runas.exe /netonly /noprofile /user:domainadm@domain "powershell.exe -
noprofile -File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Powershell_scripts\New-
ADuser\.ps1" -verb RunAs"
```

It works like a charm now!

Hope it will help anyone in need. ;)

Comment: Better way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838760/run-a-powershell-script-from-batch-file-with-elevated-privileges

Answer (score -1):

you can start powershell with another credentials

```
@echo off
cls
echo Sign in with your ADM ID  
set/P user="*     user: "
rem set/P pass="* password: "
set "psCmd=powershell -Command "$pwd = read-host '* password' -AsSecureString; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd); [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%P in (`%psCmd%`) do set "pass=%%P"

powershell -executionpolicy bypass -Command "$p='%pass%'|convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force;$c=new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential('%user%',$p);start-process 'powershell' '-Command "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Powershell_scripts\New-ADuser\New-Aduser_test.ps1"' -credential $c -passthru -wait; read-host;"
exit/B
```

or simply

```
@echo off
cls

powershell -executionpolicy bypass -Command "start-process 'powershell' '-Command "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Powershell_scripts\New-ADuser\New-Aduser_test.ps1"' -credential $c -passthru -wait; read-host;"
exit/B
```

that will prompt for credentials

Comment: Your script does not work. I get the error username or password incorrect. I actually need to execute that script with domain admin account. I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: I did but it did not work either. It errors (in French originally) : user cannot open that type of opening on that computer.

Comment: Very bad idea to use `cmd.exe`'s `set /p` command to get a password as it is visible when typed.

Comment: Why spawn PowerShell from `cmd.exe` when you can just write a PowerShell script and run it directly in PowerShell?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, please see the OP question

Comment: The question was meant to be rhetorical here. I asked the OP the same question.

Comment: @elzooilogico, no it does not work... It errors and open a new PS window. Why is it so complicated? I think I need to clarify my project. A colleague of mine has made a form from Excel which gathers all the information related to the new user. There is a button in this form which calls a .bat file that executes that PS script with elevated privileges in turn.