# Get registry key HKCU without credential prompt in powershell

Tags: powershell

I run a script as administrator, and since I'm administrator there must be a way to get what I want without PS asking me for user credentials.

here is sample method to get programs installed by user locally, I need a version which will not ask me to input password.

```
function Get-UserPrograms
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName "DESKTOP" -Credential "DESKTOP\USER" -ScriptBlock {
        $regpath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"

        Get-ItemProperty $regpath |
        .{process{if($_.DisplayName -and $_.InstallLocation) { $_ } }} |
        Select-Object DisplayName, Publisher, InstallLocation |
        Sort-Object  DisplayName
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945292/run-powershell-script-via-batch-file-with-elevated-privileges

Comment: the solution in that link asks for password, and also runs new powershell console which disapears ASAP.

Comment: Have you considered using the `[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]` .NET class instead of using `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: from what i can tell, when running certain calls via `I-C`, you MUST run the `Invoke-Command` call from an elevated session OR provide elevated credentials. this seems to be built into `I-C` and you seem to have found one of the many such accesses that require elevation. [*grin*]

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yes, already tried that with `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::CurrentUser` which does not work, however!!, `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::Users` does the job, I now only need to write a function to get `SID` number for each user and `Invoke-Command` is no longer needed! thank you for suggestion!

Comment: Using the hive HKCU is only valid if you're interested in interrogating registry entries for a user that is currently logged on to the target computer. For converting between SIDs and usernames in either direction, so that you can interrogate HKU, look to the `[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]` and `[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]` .NET classes.